# vb.net microsoft reportviewer - I need help to make a table fit in one page

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

How can I fill the page with empty table rows? For example; I have 2 records in the dataset but I want to the page with empty rows (draw the table borders until the end of page)

I have;
[image]

I want;
[image: asd]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting your report data from a database?  If so you might look at returning empty rows from your database call.

If you can describe your data source and query that you are using for this report, we might be able to suggest changes to the query to return blank rows.

**UPDATE:**

OK, Based on how you describe the data you are getting, perhaps you can change your database call to do something like this:

```
select * from Subeler where Subeler.FirmaId = 10
UNION ALL
select TOP 5 ' ' from Subeler where 1 = 1
```

That will give you your original data, plus 5 "blank" rows to help pad your report. Of course you would have to make sure the second query has the same number and type of columns as your first, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: I create a list of objects, fill the list from database and set the list as report datasource. Simplified query: "select * from Subeler where Subeler.FirmaId = 10" I add all records in the reader to the list.

Comment: I create objects with empty fields and add them into the list -which I use as datasource for the report-. But this is my temporary solution because in this way I can add a fixed number of empty rows which may run over the page. I think the way you mentioned is similiar to what I did. This is not the exact solution I'm looking for.